# Does 64-bit RISC-V RV64 allow access to the low 32 bits of registers?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, riscv

I am working with a 64 bit RISC processor, and I have question can we access the lower 32 part of the 64 bit register separately? As in case of AArch64 where x0 is for entire 64-bit register and w0 corresponds to the 32 bit part of the same register.

Do we have this kind of feature in RISC-V?

Comment: RISC-V's `x0` is hard-wired to zero.  And [riscv32] only has 32-bit registers.  But near duplicate of [Why did RV64 introduce new opcodes for 32-bit operations instead of the 64-bit ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42627337)

Answer (score 1):

64-bit RISC-V has 64-bit registers.  Instead of using a different register name to indicate 32-bit operations, they use a different mnemonic (e.g. `addw` for a single 32-bit word width vs. `add` for the full register).  Most(?) instructions are available in a 32-bit form as well as the full-width form.

```
int add(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}

long long add64(long long a,long long b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Compiled by GCC10.2 for rv64gc [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27int+add(int+a,int+b)%7B%0A++++return+a%2Bb%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Along+long+add64(long+long+a,long+long+b)%7B%0A++++return+a%2Bb%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:52.25039981722642,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:rv64-cgcc1020,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%271%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27RISC-V+rv64gc+gcc+10.2.0+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.74960018277359,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
add:
        addw    a0,a0,a1
        ret
add64:
        add     a0,a0,a1
        ret
```

See also [Does it makes sense for a clean-slate 64-bit instruction set only have 64-bit registers, if we don't care about backwards compat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059014/does-it-makes-sense-for-a-clean-slate-64-bit-instruction-set-only-have-64-bit-re/73059200#73059200) re: how it's just a matter of asm syntax for MIPS/RISC-V with different mnemonics vs. AArch64 with reg names.

(Although having special mnemonics makes it clearer that not every 64-bit instruction necessarily has a 32-bit operand-size version.  e.g. `auipc` doesn't need a form that truncates an address to 32-bit.)

See also [Why did RV64 introduce new opcodes for 32-bit operations instead of the 64-bit ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627337/why-did-rv64-introduce-new-opcodes-for-32-bit-operations-instead-of-the-64-bit-o) re: the design decision. Further related:

- [RV64 with RV32 instructions support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225043/rv64-with-rv32-instructions-support)
- [RISC-V 32/64-bit compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403515/risc-v-32-64-bit-compatibility-issues)